# SW:L, in Trials of the Dragon, Trial of Fire - which solution is the right one?

Tags: the-secret-world, secret-world-legends

In Secret World: Legends, the Draculesti have the Trials of the Dragon quest which TSW had, too. There are a number of different solutions to be found - but which one does actually work?

Answer (score 1):

First off, finding the solution yourself is much more rewarding.
There are "cold" tiles, switches for the wall-off-fire things, and hot tiles; hot and cold swap each time you go on another tile. Keep in mind you can go diagonal as well, and - at some cost - also go a bit longer than just the next tile.

OK, if you really want to know - this puzzle has been changed several times; for the current pattern at time of this writing, a working solution is found at https://wiki.crygaia.org/view/Trials_of_the_Dragon

> [image: Trial of Fire solutions]